# node-ffi callback error when DLL return Chinese char *

Tags: node.js, node-ffi

I have a DLL, declare like this:

```
READIDCARD_API typedef void(*PIDDataCB)(char * pData);   

READIDCARD_API int initReadIdcard(PIDDataCB func);
```

DLL Download：[the 32-bit dll file (google drive download)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13JinraIr3N_6V_VrIfgHyB4_jW2V1s0f/view?usp=sharing)

*the dll file worked well, when use QT load it and convert data use local8bit*

I use node.js and node-ffi to load it

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
const ref = require("ref");

let ReadIdcard = ffi.Library('./ReadIdcard.dll', {
  'initReadIdcard': ['int', ['pointer']]
});

let callback = ffi.Callback('void', ['string'],
  function(data) {
    console.log("data: ", data);
  });

console.log("registering the callback");
let z = ReadIdcard.initReadIdcard(callback);
console.log('done');

// Make an extra reference to the callback pointer to avoid GC
process.on('exit', function() {
  callback
});
```

My environment：Windows7 64bit / Node.js 32bit

run the code, and the ������˼�������� is Chinese before the "sorry" string

[image]

What should I do, or convert it to display right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct encoding to log the string.
Default encoding is utf8, but Chinese should be one of these utf16/gb18030/ gbk/gb2312.